# Why do you have to create instances of ActionListeners in Java?

Tags: java, static, instance, actionlistener

When I create an ActionListener, eg. for a button, I have to create an instance of the ActionListener. Especially when I have several Buttons I say

```
button1.addActionListener(new MyOwnListener());
```

and somewhere else in the code I just create another instance

```
button2.addActionListener(new MyOwnListener());
```

because I'm too lazy to use the same instance two times.

However, isn't this wasting of space, when you create so many useless instances. Why can't the Listener be static?

```
MyOwnListener.actionPerformed(event);
```

instead of

```
yetAnotherInstance.actionPerformed(event);
```

I can't imagine a situtation where this wouldn't work. You don't need to differentiate between Listeners of the same class, you just create instances because you have to.

I hope you get what I want to say, even if my english isn't good.

Comment: Because `static` belongs to a class rather than an instance, how will you apply this to a *specific* object?

Comment: How would you tell the `Button` to call that?

Comment: Of course I meant the method.

Comment: Sorry I don't know to explain that in a good way :/

Comment: "because I'm too lazy to use the same instance two times." I don't follow what this means.

Comment: How would each button perform a different action then? If they share the same action the listener executes?

Comment: Why can't you do something like `MyOwnListener l = new MyOwnListener();` then apply it to many buttons like `button1.addActionListener(l);` & `button2.addActionListener(l);`

Comment: @DavieBrown I'm to lazy to do what Takendarkk said.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use a single instance! It's just a mess, as it is a monolithic event handler.

**Example:**

```
MyOwnListener myOwnListener = new MyOwnListener();
button1.addActionListener(myOwnListener);
button2.addActionListener(myOwnListener);
```

In which case

```
public class MyOwnListener implements ActionListener {
     @Override
     public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
         if(e.getSource() == button1) {
             executeCodeForButton1();
         } else if(e.getSource() == button2) {
             executeCodeForButton2();
         }
     }
}
```

It becomes kinda messy with multiple buttons, and harder to refactor.

EDIT: One instance and global object, singleton pattern

```
public class YourFrame extends JFrame {

    JButton button1;
    JButton button2;

    public YourFrame() {
        ...
        button1 = new JButton("Hello");
        button2 = new JButton("World");
        button1.addActionListener(YourOwnListener.INSTANCE);
        button2.addActionListener(YourOwnListener.INSTANCE);
    }

    public static enum YourOwnListener implements ActionListener {
        INSTANCE;

        private YourOwnListener() {}

        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
            if(e.getSource() == button1) {
                executeMethodForButton1();
            } else if(e.getSource() == button2) {
                executeMethodForButton2();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

But this is also using an instance. It's because they are implementing the `Observer` pattern. The listener implementation represents the function that runs when the action is performed, this is akin to a function in Javascript, or a function pointer in C/C++.

Comment: But you anyway create an instance. I think there's no way to do this without creating an instance. However, my question was, why there's no way.

Comment: Even static objects have one instance of it, enums for example.

Answer (score 0):

1. If you create a static listener method, how do you tell your button to call that method in case of an event? There is no such thing like a function pointer that you can pass to your button's `addActionListener(...)` method.
   (Since java 8, there is such a thing, but that's another story).
2. In most of the cases, different buttons have different meanings and should execute different code anyway.
3. Having all your code in static methods has nothing to do with object oriented programming. This is not necessarily a bad thing, but evidence that you are doing it wrong...
4. If you are afraid of having too many instances of the same listener, share them! Lazyness is no excuse for bad programming. (But if you share instances, make sure they do not hold any state information that you don't want to share too!)
5. Since Java 8, you can do:

   button1.addListener(MyOwnListener::actionPerformed);
   button2.addListener(MyOwnListener::actionPerformed);

Happy?

Comment: 1 I know that it wasn't possible (till Java 8 ^^), 3 Of course it's bad code when you program static where it should be object oriented. However, I think it's also bad, when you do it the other way round. You would create no instance of Math, because its not necessary for Math. I think it should be the same way with ActionListeners. 5. I'm happy with it. That's what I searched for.

Comment: Happy => good! ;) I just wanted to point out that the way it is right now is the better one. And since Java 8, you have the choice anyway. Please note that you can't remove the Java-8-static-method listener any more as two such method references are not equal to each other.